# Wrong reference to appendix section

Tags: nameref

I'm using a macro that is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717316/how-to-make-appendix-appear-in-toc-in-latex) (see the first answer), to automatically add section numbering to \nameref.

When dealing with an appendix, instead of adding the reference number of the appendix section, it adds the reference number of the current section.

Any correction?

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\appendix@section[1]{%
\refstepcounter{section}%
\orig@section*{Appendix \@Alph\c@section~: #1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix \@Alph\c@section~: #1}%
}
\let\orig@section\section
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\let\section\appendix@section}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{My first section}
\section{My second section}

The reference \ref{ApendixA} is displayed correctly. \\
The reference B in : \nameref{ApendixA} is not correct. It refers to the     alphabetical numbering of section 2, instead of the reference A in the appendix.


\appendix
\section{Biblio} \label{ApendixA}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can try with `\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}` (after hyperref). See the documentation of gettitlestring for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you sooo much @UlrikeFischer. It works !

Comment: I don't believe `\nameref` (`\@currentlabelname`) has ever been standardized.  `\refstepcounter`, `\label` and `\newlabel` have to be modified to support it.